# A question on the definition of the Lebesgue integral without measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In my book the Lebesgue integral is defined, with no reference to measure, as follows:[image]

and the authors proceed to show that the integral is well-defined in the sense that if two different sequences of step functions, $f_n$ and $g_n$ satisfy (a) and (b) then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int g_n$. This is fine but it is followed by a very confusing paragraph:

[image]

Could you please explain to me why this is the case based on what we know? In particular, I don't see why the function $f$ must vanish outside of $(a,b)$ and why the sequence cannot exist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have not told us what the "admissible" step functions are, and how $\int f$ for a step function is defined. I think that measure theory is the grey energy in these concepts.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for your comment. Step functions are defined the usual way $f = \sum \lambda_n f_n$ where $f_n$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[a_n,b_n)$ and $\int f = \sum \lambda_n \left(b_n-\alpha_n\right)$, the regular Riemann integral. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Copying a page like that, I think one could at least mention what book one is using.

Comment: @mickep No problem, I am using Introduction to Hilbert spaces with applications by Debnath. Do you have any idea why the author seems to think the above?